# PHP development for online games

Tags: performance, php, online, protocol

I am not pro on programming and games but i had developed an online browser-based game with php . Now i am creating a game like a chess that it do not needs an live-stream and FPS data exchanges.

I want to know is my knowledge about php and tcp protocol is enough to develop such a game ? or i need to develop on other language and do not use tcp protocol ( use UDP instead ) .

And one thing more ... Can i develop with php on a UDP protocol ? where can i get little information about udp and programming on it.

thank you very much :)